# General questions about AWS Ethereum network

Tags: amazon-web-services, ethereum, amazon-managed-blockchain, nethereum

I followed these steps and I believe I have an ethereum network running successfully:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/blockchain-templates/latest/developerguide/blockchain-templates-getting-started.html

After starting the network, I have a bastion host to create a SSH tunnel, and I added the FoxyProxy extension to Chrome, and then I am able to connect to the explorer URL and stats URL, shown below.

Here are some general questions I am struggling with:

1. The explorer URL shows blocks, but the stats URL looks empty, why is that?
2. There is a EthJsonRPCURL with the description "Use this URL to access the Geth JSON RPC of your Ethereum Clients, or input it into Metamask" and I am trying to use that to deploy a smart contract. If I want to do this from Visual Studio, how would I do it? When I try, I get a timeout error. To connect to the other URL's I am using the proxy through the browser, but what would I do in Visual Studio to connect to the network using the json rpc URL to deploy a smart contract?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe at  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/ you may find help as well?

Comment: I don't understand why people use these (automated) tools like AWS or Truffle to deoploy their contracts. I never use that. Once I have read the article "Deploying a smart contract the hard way" written by Gustavo Guimares on Medium I don't need any tool out there, I just send the transaction to `geth` and that's it.

Comment: Hi Nulik, my question is more about making a request to my network rather than my method of deploying a contract. I can't even connect to the AWS instance I created so that is where I am stuck. When I do curl, I get timeout, so not sure how to do that with SSH tunnel? curl POST http://internal-clear-LoadB-1S1A8EPOZ1FVF-1813149978.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8545 --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[]}'